# How to modify homepage of Delegate Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, wordpress-theming

I have a website that is created in **Wordpress Delegate Theme**. I want to insert a snow animation effect in background of the website (all website pages). I tried to include the snow.php in the index.php but the page template becomes broken.

This is my snow.php (I got it from **[Falling Snow Effect](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/the_falling_snow_effect.htm)**)

**CSS:**

```
#snowflakeContainer 
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .snowflake 
        {
            padding-left: 15px;
            font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 24px;
            position: fixed;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            user-select: none;
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        .snowflake:hover 
        {
            cursor: default;
        }
```

**This is my HTML codes**

```
    <!-- div for snow -->
    <div id="snowflakeContainer">
        <p class="snowflake">*</p>
    </div>

<!-- Javascript for snow -->
<script src="http://www.kirupa.com/js/fallingsnow_v6.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.kirupa.com/js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
```

I need a help in inserting it in the website without template/page broken. Please guide me in what to do and what php file should I edit and insert this snow.php.

Comment: You should do this in a child theme.  That won't fix your problem, but it will isolate your customizations.

Comment: What specific error do you get?

Comment: @J0e3gan The error I got is the page template is broken. The header goes to the top and the slider is not functioning. The posts container gets bigger the same with the text. The snow effect is there but the template background (background color) is only in half page of the website and the remaining part in the bottom of the page is now in white color (default background color).